# Audio tag does not appear after hiding and showing an iframe again?

Tags: html, ipad, css, audio, iframe

I've a page loaded within an iframe which may contain audio/video tags. But in iPad, I noticed that hiding the iframe and showing it again, disappears the tags.

```
<button onclick="toggle();">Toggle Iframe</button>
<iframe id='page' src='http://www.quackit.com/common/html_editor_form.cfm?contentFile=../html_5/tags/inc_html_audio_tag.cfm' width="100%" frameborder='1'></iframe>

<script>
    function toggle() {
        var $el = $('#page');
        if ($el.is(':visible')) {
            $el.hide();
        } else {
            $el.show();
        }
}
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/sQVCd/

Is there any fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I tried is to hide the iframe using `visibility` property which worked for me on iPad also.

```
if ($el.css('visibility') === 'visible') {
  $el.css('visibility', 'hidden');
} else {
  $el.css('visibility', 'visible');
}
```